# Limit TTY via SSH to local Network

Tags: ssh, tty, openssh

I'm setting up a JumpHost for my local network, and would like to not allow TTY from outside, but would also like to have it enabled for connections from inside the network. Is that possible, and if so how?

PS: I know the `PermitTTY` option, my question is about how to only allow it from inside the network

Comment: Don't forward any network ports to the computer.

Comment: That would make for a relatively bad JumpHost :D